How to shorten the code with discord py cogs?
I have a code like this, and I have to repeat the check function every time in every game. How can i do it better?
class Casino(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    group = app_commands.Group(name="casino", description="description")

    async def balance_check(self, interaction, bet):
        if bet > balance(interaction.user.id):
          await intreaction.response.send_message('Not enough money')
          return False
        return True

   @group.command(description='slots game')
    async def slots(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, bet: str):
        res = await self.balance_check(interaction, bet)
        if res is False:
            return
       ....


    @group.command(description='slots game')
    async def big_hunt(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, bet: str):
        res = await self.balance_check(interaction, bet)
        if res is False:
            return
       ....


I tried to use event command on_interaction and make decorator money checker

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

discogs-api is the wrong tag.
